# How to put bullet points and enumeration numbers into the page margin with HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to present lists in a document using a style like in the right image below:

[image: Bullet points in the page margin to the right]

The content of the list items is a typeset like any other `<p>` and bullet points are in the margin.

Is there a CSS solution?

Comment: I would say that the text below has a left margin rather than the bullets being in the margin

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so that it could be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

depending how you structure your html this will work, just Run the code snippet to check it out:

make sure the body has the same font-size than the list elements in order to get the easily the same line height:

```css
body{ font-size:20px;}
.no_bullet:first-of-type{ 
  margin-bottom:-20px
}
.no_bullet:last-of-type{ 
  margin-top:-20px
}
```

```html
<ul class="no_bullet">
any header
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius postea pertinacia ex, usu ea forensibus interesset, vis modo veniam an. Has suas probo vituperata ea. Inermis eligendi per at, ut purto prodesset usu. Vel in stet oporteat senserit. Ius id populo latine neglegentur, cum te homero malorum molestie.

Vis delenit alienum an, cu movet officiis sed. Vis ipsum commune ei, his ei partem accusam molestiae, paulo indoctum interpretaris ei mea. Unum accusata ea vis, mea ipsum falli conclusionemque eu, at vim mutat eirmod salutatus. Et aeque disputando est. Ius falli numquam mentitum in, mei ex novum eirmod, pri deserunt reprehendunt ad.
</li>
  <li>bla</li>
  <li>gla</li>
</ul>
<ul class="no_bullet">
any footer
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to work with `Padding`. You can simply add a class and set `list-style:none`. It will work if you need some padding/margin for all `li`.

See the Snippet below:

```css
li.nolist{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="nolist">What is Lorem Ipsum?</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
    <li class="nolist">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```